# How many users can a 200mb ASP.NET membership database hold?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-membership

I just purchased an unlimited shared hosting windows account on godaddy with 2 databases only to realise that they have a 200mb limit on SQL Server databases. My website uses the automatically generated ASP.NET 2.0 membership database. The nature of my website (free classifieds) requires the storage of a significant number of users.

Since I'm using the standard ASP.NET membership database that (hopefully) many of you have used before... I was wondering just how many users a 200 mb database could hold?

Comment: Zero. We do not have appropriate technology for serializing human beings, though research is going on in that aspect.

Comment: totally unexpected ! lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on your other information in the ASP.NET membership table (applications, roles etc.) - but I did a quick experiment to get a rough idea:

```
Users      Disk space used on disk (MB)
------      ----------------------------
 5'000                5.5 MB
10'000                8.9 MB
25'000               18.1 MB
50'000               33.8 MB
```

If you do a rough estimate, this means, with 200 MB limit you should be able to support 250'000 users or more - enough for you?

Marc

Comment: thanks! info really helps.
actually 250'000 is more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to store. Obviously, if you have many fields, then it will be fewer than a table with less fields.

Comment: Modifying the generated Aspnet membership database will defeat the whole purpose of using it in the 1st place...i.e to save time...and in any case modifying the tables will crash the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the below link and generate some report using number of users (Active) in last 6 months.

[Get size of all tables in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database)

The above article will help you get actual size of each table and you may take average to at least make some projection.