# Get size of all tables in database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have inherited a fairly large SQL Server database. It seems to take up more space than I would expect, given the data it contains.

Is there an easy way to determine how much space on disk each table is consuming?

Comment: which roles do you have access to? Are you the DBA, or is this managed through a web host, client or similar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Table and Index size in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316831/table-and-index-size-in-sql-server)

Comment: @RobAllen I have full access to the database, so a script that requires any role is sufficient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you tell what Tables are taking up the most space in a SQL Server 2005 Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927231/how-can-you-tell-what-tables-are-taking-up-the-most-space-in-a-sql-server-2005-d)

Comment: What seems to me a cleaner solution can be found in this (my) answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719990/9117) to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606366/how-to-find-the-size-of-a-table-in-sql/3719990#3719990).

Answer (score 3444, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS TableName,
    s.name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.object_id > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.name, s.name, p.rows
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC, t.name
```

Comment: Silly question, but is it possible that this query can cause row locking?

Comment: @GEMI: any SELECT typically has *shared (read) locks* on rows - yes.

Comment: Indexes use space too, and the amount space used by indexes can be found with this [query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/#17600911) below.

Comment: Your script has problems with filtered indexes: For each filtered index for a given table, I see an extra row with that tables's name in the results. The "RowCounts" of each of those extra rows corresponds to the number of rows covered by one of the filtered indexes. (on Sql2012)

Comment: If your tables are partitioned, they show up multiple times without any indication of what is going on.  You can either add p.partition_number to the select list or you can SUM(p.Rows) and remove it from the group by.

Comment: output has duplicates

Comment: *output has duplicates*. I saw this too. `sys.partitions.rows` is documented to be an approximate number of rows. I had a table where the estimated rows varied from index to index. Take the `MIN`, `MAX` or `AVG` of `rows` if you want to mitigate this problem.

Comment: if you are doing a long running operation (such as a bulk delete) you will temporarily get the table name twice. internally I don't know what it's doing but I assume it is something like a 'copy' of the table that could be rolled back to. I assume many people will use this query to see which tables need 'purging' and if you run it again during the delete you'll see duplicate rows. this may be occuring too on 'busy' databases hence the recommendations to take rowcount averages. it will disappear once the table has 'settled down'. (keep an eye on row count)

Comment: If you use partitions then try using the sql script below provide by @xav. This rolled up the tables nicely and had accurate values for row counts.  Simply doing a sum on p.rows does not yield accurate results.

Comment: Can someone explain the purpose of the line

    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%'

Comment: @Perposterer: to exclude the `dtproperties` table that the SSMS diagramming support includes in your database. It's not one of your tables - so you typically don't need to know / don't care how big it is ....

Comment: For anyone facing duplicate rows due to filtered index(who need actual rows of table) just add one more where condition of `AND i.filter_definition IS NULL`.

Comment: @Grigory: the indexes take up space, too - that's why they're being included in this report. It will **NOT** duplicate any space taken, however - in the case of a heap (table *without* clustered index), the index id = 0 **is** the data - any other index is a non-clustered index. For a table with a clustered index, the data is in leaf level of index_id = 1 - the clustered index - again: **no duplication**, all other indexes are separate nonclustered indices

Comment: To fix the duplicate rows due to filtered indexes, you can remove the group by on p.Rows, and change the select for "p.rows" to "max(p.rows) as rows" (since the filtered indexes have smaller row counts, but the heap or clustered index will have the correct count and will be returned by the max).  Tested on several enterprise databases, including a database which has over 12.5k tables. @marc_s This is an excellent answer, thanks! I've used it many times over the years and just ran into the filtered index issue recently.

Comment: Hi, usually is also usefull add 

`,case when p.rows> 0 then SUM(a.used_pages) * 8.0/p.rows else 0 end as kb_row`

to know space used by row (statistical)

Answer (score 775):

If you are using **SQL Server Management Studio** (SSMS), instead of running a query (*which in my case returned duplicate rows*) you can run a **standard report**.

1. Right click on the database
2. Navigate to **Reports > Standard Reports > Disk Usage By Table**

Note: The database compatibility level must be set to 90 or above for this to work correctly. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb510680.aspx

Note: This report isn't available when working with and Azure SQL database

Comment: In Management Studio 2012 you can do: View-Object Explorer Details (F7) and navigate to "Tables" in Object Explorer. In Details right-click on the header and select size columns.

Comment: You can even sort by clicking the headers, and even export to Excel (I do this to get an average row size)

Comment: Are these values in KB or KiB? At the size I am dealing with, the difference is meaningful. I know many products list KB when they are actually KiB.

Comment: @SixOThree Because SSMS says "KB" and not "KiB" we have to assume it actually means "KB". You could add up the values of all the tables yourself and compare it to the size of the .mdf file in File Explorer, I suppose.

Comment: I can't find the "Disk Usage by Table" option. I'm using SSMS 19 and SQL Azure Database.

Comment: @JeeShenLee this report isn't available when using an SQL Azure Database. I'd suggest use the script in the answer from marc_s.

Answer (score 135):

sp_spaceused can get you information on the disk space used by a table, indexed view, or the whole database.

For example:

```
USE MyDatabase; GO

EXEC sp_spaceused N'User.ContactInfo'; GO
```

This reports the disk usage information for the ContactInfo table.

To use this for all tables at once:

```
USE MyDatabase; GO

sp_msforeachtable 'EXEC sp_spaceused [?]' GO
```

You can also get disk usage from within the right-click Standard Reports functionality of SQL Server.  To get to this report, navigate from the server object in Object Explorer, move down to the Databases object, and then right-click any database. From the menu that appears, select Reports, then Standard Reports, and then "Disk Usage by Partition: [DatabaseName]".

Comment: This is neat although the use of `sp_msforeachtable` in SSMS easily might trigger a `System.OutOfMemoryException` if you have a large number of tables, so it might be a better idea to use a temporary table to store the results.

Comment: The main problem I can see with sp_spacedused is that it appears to return the data in human readable format (e.g. in the 'reserved' column in my case it had '152 KB'). I assume this will switch to MB/GB as appropriate. This is clearly useful in a lot of situations but not if you need to apply some logic based on the size, or want to compare values or whatever. I looked for a way of turning that off, but I couldn't spot one (I'm using SQL Server 2005 :()

Comment: `sp_msforeachtable` is not available in SQL Azure...

Comment: Concise, but effective.

Answer (score 78):

Here is another method: using *SQL Server Management Studio*, in **Object Explorer**, go to your database and select **Tables**

[image]

Then open the **Object Explorer Details** (either by pressing **F7** or going to *View->Object Explorer Details*). In the object explorer details page, right click on the column header and enable the columns that you would like to see in the page. You can sort the data by any column too.

[image]

Comment: @batmaci Not sure if this was working at all when you made your comment about Azure SQL databases, but it seems to at least be partially working now in the recent versions of SSMS.  For me it seems the query for table metadata is timing out, but before it does it seems to return a few (3-10) tables worth, including (reliably) the selected table. Select a table and click refresh to see the table you want if it's not displayed.

Comment: You can also export the list in a CSV file by using an utility like NirSoft SysExporter: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sysexp.html

Comment: for [Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57223379/1042705) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57223379/1042705) should work

Answer (score 59):

```
 exec  sp_spaceused N'dbo.MyTable'
```

For all tables ,use..(adding from the comments of Paul)

```
exec sp_MSForEachTable 'exec sp_spaceused [?]'
```

Comment: **Sneaky** - you changed from `exec sp_helpdb` which **doesn't** show anything about tables, to `exec sp_spaceused` which does - but only for one table at a time... it doesn't give you an overview of what tables you have and how much rows they have and how much space they take up.

Comment: exec sp_MSForEachTable 'exec sp_spaceused [?]'

Comment: Is there a way to sum the results for each table?

Answer (score 49):

After some searching, I could not find an easy way to get information on all of the tables. There is a handy stored procedure named sp_spaceused that will return all of the space used by the database. If provided with a table name, it returns the space used by that table. However, the results returned by the stored procedure are not sortable, since the columns are character values.

The following script will generate the information I'm looking for.

```
create table #TableSize (
    Name varchar(255),
    [rows] int,
    reserved varchar(255),
    data varchar(255),
    index_size varchar(255),
    unused varchar(255))
create table #ConvertedSizes (
    Name varchar(255),
    [rows] int,
    reservedKb int,
    dataKb int,
    reservedIndexSize int,
    reservedUnused int)

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="insert into #TableSize
EXEC sp_spaceused '?'"
insert into #ConvertedSizes (Name, [rows], reservedKb, dataKb, reservedIndexSize, reservedUnused)
select name, [rows], 
SUBSTRING(reserved, 0, LEN(reserved)-2), 
SUBSTRING(data, 0, LEN(data)-2), 
SUBSTRING(index_size, 0, LEN(index_size)-2), 
SUBSTRING(unused, 0, LEN(unused)-2)
from #TableSize

select * from #ConvertedSizes
order by reservedKb desc

drop table #TableSize
drop table #ConvertedSizes
```

Answer (score 46):

For Azure I used this:

You should have SSMS v17.x+

I used;

[image]

With this, as User  [Sparrow has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48326827/1042705):

Open your `Databases`> and select **Tables**,

Then press key **F7**
You should see the `row count`

as:
[image]

SSMS *here* is connected to Azure databases

Comment: It has a problem with memory optimized tables, (i just tested after seeing this post :)

Comment: Right-click the columns to show additional properties, such as index-space, or data-space used.

Answer (score 40):

Above queries are good for finding the amount of space used by the table (indexes included), but if you want to compare how much space is used by indexes on the table use this query:

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
    i.name AS IndexName,
    i.index_id AS IndexID,
    8 * SUM(a.used_pages) AS 'Indexsize(KB)'
FROM
    sys.indexes AS i
    JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.OBJECT_ID = i.OBJECT_ID AND p.index_id = i.index_id
    JOIN sys.allocation_units AS a ON a.container_id = p.partition_id
WHERE
    i.is_primary_key = 0 -- fix for size discrepancy
GROUP BY
    i.OBJECT_ID,
    i.index_id,
    i.name
ORDER BY
    OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID),
    i.index_id
```

Comment: What is the reason that summing up the Indexsize(KB) column for a particular table disagrees with the index_size from sp_spaceused?

Comment: @Derek Fixed his answer by adding `where [i].[is_primary_key] = 0`. Now the sizes should match.

Comment: Thank you, but this actually isn't working out either.  I have a (very small) test database, the table of interest has two indexes - a primary clustered index on one column and a non-clustered index on two of the other columns.  This query says each of them is using 16kB, but sp_spaceused says total index usage is 24kB.  Part of my confusion is this: Comparing this query to the "UsedSpaceKB" of the accepted answer, I don't see a real difference.  Same joins, just missing the addition of sys.tables.  Am I missing something, or is this query inherently broken?

Comment: I have large databases. And sizes match with `sp_spaceused`. I measure GBs so a few megs not matching is not much. I don't care about exact sizes, just an idea.

Answer (score 34):

Marc_s' answer gives **incorrect** results when working with multiple **partitions** and/or **filtered indexes**. It also doesn't distinguish between the size of the data and indexes, which is often very relevant. Several suggested fixes don't address the core problem or are simply wrong as well.

The following query addresses all of those issues.

```
SELECT 
     [object_id]        = t.[object_id]
    ,[schema_name]      = s.[name]
    ,[table_name]       = t.[name]
    ,[index_name]       = CASE WHEN i.[type] in (0,1,5) THEN null    ELSE i.[name] END -- 0=Heap; 1=Clustered; 5=Clustered Columnstore
    ,[object_type]      = CASE WHEN i.[type] in (0,1,5) THEN 'TABLE' ELSE 'INDEX'  END
    ,[index_type]       = i.[type_desc]
    ,[partition_count]  = p.partition_count
    ,[row_count]        = p.[rows]
    ,[data_compression] = CASE WHEN p.data_compression_cnt > 1 THEN 'Mixed'
                               ELSE (  SELECT DISTINCT p.data_compression_desc
                                       FROM sys.partitions p
                                       WHERE i.[object_id] = p.[object_id] AND i.index_id = p.index_id
                                    )
                          END
    ,[total_space_MB]   = cast(round(( au.total_pages                  * (8/1024.00)), 2) AS DECIMAL(36,2))
    ,[used_space_MB]    = cast(round(( au.used_pages                   * (8/1024.00)), 2) AS DECIMAL(36,2))
    ,[unused_space_MB]  = cast(round(((au.total_pages - au.used_pages) * (8/1024.00)), 2) AS DECIMAL(36,2))
FROM sys.schemas s
JOIN sys.tables  t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
JOIN (
    SELECT [object_id], index_id, partition_count=count(*), [rows]=sum([rows]), data_compression_cnt=count(distinct [data_compression])
    FROM sys.partitions
    GROUP BY [object_id], [index_id]
) p ON i.[object_id] = p.[object_id] AND i.[index_id] = p.[index_id]
JOIN (
    SELECT p.[object_id], p.[index_id], total_pages = sum(a.total_pages), used_pages = sum(a.used_pages), data_pages=sum(a.data_pages)
    FROM sys.partitions p
    JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.[partition_id] = a.[container_id]
    GROUP BY p.[object_id], p.[index_id]
) au ON i.[object_id] = au.[object_id] AND i.[index_id] = au.[index_id]
WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0 -- Not a system table
```

Answer (score 24):

Extension to @xav [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36612128/2452669) that handled table partitions to get size in MB and GB.
Tested on SQL Server 2008/2012 (Commented a line where `is_memory_optimized = 1`)

```
SELECT
    a2.name AS TableName,
    a1.rows as [RowCount],
    --(a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) * 8 AS ReservedSize_KB,
    --a1.data * 8 AS DataSize_KB,
    --(CASE WHEN (a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used,0)) > a1.data THEN (a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used,0)) - a1.data ELSE 0 END) * 8 AS IndexSize_KB,
    --(CASE WHEN (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) > a1.used THEN (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) - a1.used ELSE 0 END) * 8 AS UnusedSize_KB,
    CAST(ROUND(((a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS ReservedSize_MB,
    CAST(ROUND(a1.data * 8 / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS DataSize_MB,
    CAST(ROUND((CASE WHEN (a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used,0)) > a1.data THEN (a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used,0)) - a1.data ELSE 0 END) * 8 / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS IndexSize_MB,
    CAST(ROUND((CASE WHEN (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) > a1.used THEN (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) - a1.used ELSE 0 END) * 8 / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSize_MB,
    --'| |' Separator_MB_GB,
    CAST(ROUND(((a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) * 8) / 1024.00 / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS ReservedSize_GB,
    CAST(ROUND(a1.data * 8 / 1024.00 / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS DataSize_GB,
    CAST(ROUND((CASE WHEN (a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used,0)) > a1.data THEN (a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used,0)) - a1.data ELSE 0 END) * 8 / 1024.00 / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS IndexSize_GB,
    CAST(ROUND((CASE WHEN (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) > a1.used THEN (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) - a1.used ELSE 0 END) * 8 / 1024.00 / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSize_GB
FROM
    (SELECT 
        ps.object_id,
        SUM (CASE WHEN (ps.index_id < 2) THEN row_count ELSE 0 END) AS [rows],
        SUM (ps.reserved_page_count) AS reserved,
        SUM (CASE
                WHEN (ps.index_id < 2) THEN (ps.in_row_data_page_count + ps.lob_used_page_count + ps.row_overflow_used_page_count)
                ELSE (ps.lob_used_page_count + ps.row_overflow_used_page_count)
            END
            ) AS data,
        SUM (ps.used_page_count) AS used
    FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
        --===Remove the following comment for SQL Server 2014+
        --WHERE ps.object_id NOT IN (SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables WHERE is_memory_optimized = 1)
    GROUP BY ps.object_id) AS a1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        it.parent_id,
        SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) AS reserved,
        SUM(ps.used_page_count) AS used
     FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
     INNER JOIN sys.internal_tables it ON (it.object_id = ps.object_id)
     WHERE it.internal_type IN (202,204)
     GROUP BY it.parent_id) AS a4 ON (a4.parent_id = a1.object_id)
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects a2  ON ( a1.object_id = a2.object_id ) 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas a3 ON (a2.schema_id = a3.schema_id)
WHERE a2.type <> N'S' and a2.type <> N'IT'
--AND a2.name = 'MyTable'       --Filter for specific table
--ORDER BY a3.name, a2.name
ORDER BY ReservedSize_MB DESC
```

Answer (score 17):

If you need to calculate exactly the same numbers, that are on 'table properties - storage' page in SSMS, you need to count them with the same method as it done in SSMS (works for sql server 2005 and above ... and also works correctly for tables with LOB fields - because just counting "used_pages" is not enought to show accurate index size):

```
;with cte as (
SELECT
t.name as TableName,
SUM (s.used_page_count) as used_pages_count,
SUM (CASE
            WHEN (i.index_id < 2) THEN (in_row_data_page_count + lob_used_page_count + row_overflow_used_page_count)
            ELSE lob_used_page_count + row_overflow_used_page_count
        END) as pages
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats  AS s 
JOIN sys.tables AS t ON s.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON i.[object_id] = t.[object_id] AND s.index_id = i.index_id
GROUP BY t.name
)
select
    cte.TableName, 
    cast((cte.pages * 8.)/1024 as decimal(10,3)) as TableSizeInMB, 
    cast(((CASE WHEN cte.used_pages_count > cte.pages 
                THEN cte.used_pages_count - cte.pages
                ELSE 0 
          END) * 8./1024) as decimal(10,3)) as IndexSizeInMB
from cte
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: can you elaborate on why `WHEN (i.index_id < 2|) THEN (in_row_data_page_count + lob_used_page_count + row_overflow_used_page_count)` gives the number of pages for the heap? In `sql server 2014` there's only one index satisfying this criteria (and that index is the primary key: i.index_id = 1). But if I compare the size with the result of sb_spaceused then they match (to a good extent)

Answer (score 17):

A small change from [Marc_s's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7892349/1501497), since I have been going back to this page so often, ordered by most row's first:

```
SELECT
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB,
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB,
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%'
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
GROUP BY
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY
    --p.rows DESC --Uncomment to order by amount rows instead of size in KB.
    SUM(a.total_pages) DESC
```

Answer (score 16):

We use table partitioning and had some trouble with the queries provided above due to duplicate records.

For those who need this, you can find below the query as run by SQL Server 2014 when generating the "Disk usage by table" report. I assume it also works with previous versions of SQL Server.

It works like a charm.

```
SELECT
    a2.name AS [tablename],
    a1.rows as row_count,
    (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0))* 8 AS reserved, 
    a1.data * 8 AS data,
    (CASE WHEN (a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used,0)) > a1.data THEN (a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used,0)) - a1.data ELSE 0 END) * 8 AS index_size,
    (CASE WHEN (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) > a1.used THEN (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) - a1.used ELSE 0 END) * 8 AS unused
FROM
    (SELECT 
        ps.object_id,
        SUM (
            CASE
                WHEN (ps.index_id < 2) THEN row_count
                ELSE 0
            END
            ) AS [rows],
        SUM (ps.reserved_page_count) AS reserved,
        SUM (
            CASE
                WHEN (ps.index_id < 2) THEN (ps.in_row_data_page_count + ps.lob_used_page_count + ps.row_overflow_used_page_count)
                ELSE (ps.lob_used_page_count + ps.row_overflow_used_page_count)
            END
            ) AS data,
        SUM (ps.used_page_count) AS used
    FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
        WHERE ps.object_id NOT IN (SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables WHERE is_memory_optimized = 1)
    GROUP BY ps.object_id) AS a1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        it.parent_id,
        SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) AS reserved,
        SUM(ps.used_page_count) AS used
     FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
     INNER JOIN sys.internal_tables it ON (it.object_id = ps.object_id)
     WHERE it.internal_type IN (202,204)
     GROUP BY it.parent_id) AS a4 ON (a4.parent_id = a1.object_id)
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects a2  ON ( a1.object_id = a2.object_id ) 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas a3 ON (a2.schema_id = a3.schema_id)
WHERE a2.type <> N'S' and a2.type <> N'IT'
ORDER BY a3.name, a2.name
```

Answer (score 10):

```
-- Show the size of all the tables in a database sort by data size descending
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @TableInfo TABLE (tablename varchar(255), rowcounts int, reserved varchar(255), DATA varchar(255), index_size varchar(255), unused varchar(255))
DECLARE @cmd1 varchar(500)
SET @cmd1 = 'exec sp_spaceused ''?'''

INSERT INTO @TableInfo (tablename,rowcounts,reserved,DATA,index_size,unused)
EXEC sp_msforeachtable @command1=@cmd1

SELECT * FROM @TableInfo ORDER BY Convert(int,Replace(DATA,' KB','')) DESC
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a way to get all tables' sizes quickly with the following steps:

1. Write the given **T-SQL commands** to list all database tables:

   ```
   select 'exec sp_spaceused ' + TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
   ```
2. Now copy the list of database tables, and copy it into a new query analyzer window

   ```
   exec sp_spaceused table1
   exec sp_spaceused table2
   exec sp_spaceused table3
   exec sp_spaceused table4
   exec sp_spaceused table5
   ```
3. In SQL **query analyzer**, select from top tool bar option **Results to file** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>).
4. Now finally hit the **Execute** button red marked from the above **tool bar**.
5. The Database **size of all tables** is now stored in a file on your computer.

   [image]

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT o.name AS ObjectName, 
       SUM(reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / 1024 AS SizeinMB
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ps
INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects AS o
ON ps.object_id = o.id
GROUP BY o.name
ORDER BY SizeinMB DESC;
```

Answer (score 6):

For get all table size in one database you can use this query :

```
Exec sys.sp_MSforeachtable ' sp_spaceused "?" '
```

And you can change it to insert all of result into temp table and after that select from temp table.

```
Insert into #TempTable Exec sys.sp_MSforeachtable ' sp_spaceused "?" ' 
Select * from #TempTable
```

Answer (score 5):

This will give you the sizes, and record counts for each table.

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- Get a list of tables and their sizes on disk
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Table_Sizes]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(500)  
DECLARE @schema_name VARCHAR(500)  
DECLARE @tab1 TABLE( 
        tablename VARCHAR (500) collate database_default 
       ,schemaname VARCHAR(500) collate database_default 
) 

CREATE TABLE #temp_Table ( 
        tablename sysname 
       ,row_count INT 
       ,reserved VARCHAR(50) collate database_default 
       ,data VARCHAR(50) collate database_default 
       ,index_size VARCHAR(50) collate database_default 
       ,unused VARCHAR(50) collate database_default  
) 

INSERT INTO @tab1  
SELECT Table_Name, Table_Schema  
FROM information_schema.tables  
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 

DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Table_Schema + '.' + Table_Name   
FROM information_schema.tables t1  
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 

OPEN c1 
FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @table_name 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN   
        SET @table_name = REPLACE(@table_name, '[','');  
        SET @table_name = REPLACE(@table_name, ']','');  

        -- make sure the object exists before calling sp_spacedused 
        IF EXISTS(SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name)) 
        BEGIN 
               INSERT INTO #temp_Table EXEC sp_spaceused @table_name, false; 
        END 

        FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @table_name 
END 
CLOSE c1 
DEALLOCATE c1 

SELECT  t1.* 
       ,t2.schemaname  
FROM #temp_Table t1  
INNER JOIN @tab1 t2 ON (t1.tablename = t2.tablename ) 
ORDER BY schemaname,t1.tablename; 

DROP TABLE #temp_Table
END
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 4):

From a command prompt using [OSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806.aspx):

```
OSQL -E -d <*databasename*> -Q "exec sp_msforeachtable 'sp_spaceused [?]'" > result.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the Tables have a more partion file & must show the file order

```
SELECT
  T1.Name                                       AS TableName,
  T5.Name                                       AS SchemaName,
  T3.partition_number                           AS PartionNumber,   
  T3.Rows                                       AS RowsCount,
  SUM(T4.total_pages) * 8                       AS TotalSpaceKB,
  SUM(T4.used_pages) * 8                        AS UsedSpaceKB,
  (SUM(T4.total_pages) - SUM(T4.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM
  sys.objects T1  INNER JOIN 
  sys.indexes T2 ON T1.object_id = T2.object_id  INNER JOIN 
  sys.partitions T3 ON T2.object_id = T3.object_id AND T2.index_id = T3.index_id  INNER JOIN
  sys.allocation_units T4 ON T3.partition_id = T4.container_id LEFT JOIN
  sys.schemas T5 ON T1.schema_id = T5.schema_id
WHERE
  T1.type='U'
GROUP BY
  T1.Name, T5.Name, T3.Rows,T3.partition_number
ORDER BY
  T1.Name,T3.partition_number;
```

Answer (score 3):

I added a few more columns on top of marc_s answer:

```
with fs
as
(
select i.object_id,
        p.rows AS RowCounts,
        SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKb
from     sys.indexes i INNER JOIN 
        sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id INNER JOIN 
         sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
    i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    i.object_id,
    p.rows
)

SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    fs.RowCounts,
    fs.TotalSpaceKb,
    t.create_date,
    t.modify_date,
    ( select COUNT(1)
        from sys.columns c 
        where c.object_id = t.object_id ) TotalColumns    
FROM 
    sys.tables t INNER JOIN      
    fs  ON t.OBJECT_ID = fs.object_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

My post is only relevant for SQL Server 2000 and has been tested to work in my environment.

This code accesses **All possible databases of a single instance**, not just a single database.

I use two temp tables to help collect the appropriate data and then dump the results into one 'Live' table.

Returned data is: DatabaseName, DatabaseTableName, Rows (in the Table), data (size of the table in KB it would seem), entry data (I find this useful for knowing when I last ran the script).

Downfall to this code is the 'data' field is not stored as an int (The chars 'KB' are kept in that field), and that would be useful (but not totally necessary) for sorting.

Hopefully this code helps someone out there and saves them some time!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_getAllDBTableSizes]

AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT OFF

   CREATE TABLE #DatabaseTables([dbname] sysname,TableName sysname)
   CREATE TABLE #AllDatabaseTableSizes(Name sysname,[rows] VARCHAR(18), reserved VARCHAR(18), data VARCHAR(18), index_size VARCHAR(18), unused VARCHAR(18))

   DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)
   SET @SQL='select ''?'' AS [Database], Table_Name from [?].information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE'' '

   INSERT INTO #DatabaseTables(DbName, TableName)
      EXECUTE sp_msforeachdb @Command1=@SQL

   DECLARE AllDatabaseTables CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FOR   
   SELECT TableName FROM #DatabaseTables

   DECLARE AllDatabaseNames CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FOR   
   SELECT DBName FROM #DatabaseTables

   DECLARE @DBName sysname  
   OPEN AllDatabaseNames  

   DECLARE @TName sysname
   OPEN AllDatabaseTables  

   WHILE 1=1 BEGIN 
      FETCH NEXT FROM AllDatabaseNames INTO @DBName  
      FETCH NEXT FROM AllDatabaseTables INTO @TName 
      IF @@FETCH_STATUS<>0 BREAK  
      INSERT INTO #AllDatabaseTableSizes
         EXEC ( 'EXEC ' + @DBName + '.dbo.sp_spaceused ' + @TName) 

   END 

   --http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175920(v=sql.80).aspx
   INSERT INTO rsp_DatabaseTableSizes (DatabaseName, name, [rows], data)
      SELECT   [dbname], name, [rows],  data FROM #DatabaseTables
      INNER JOIN #AllDatabaseTableSizes
      ON #DatabaseTables.TableName = #AllDatabaseTableSizes.Name
      GROUP BY [dbname] , name, [rows],  data
      ORDER BY [dbname]
   --To be honest, I have no idea what exact duplicates we are dropping
    -- but in my case a near enough approach has been good enough.
   DELETE FROM [rsp_DatabaseTableSizes]
   WHERE name IN 
      ( 
      SELECT name 
      FROM [rsp_DatabaseTableSizes]
      GROUP BY name
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      )

   DROP TABLE #DatabaseTables
   DROP TABLE #AllDatabaseTableSizes

   CLOSE AllDatabaseTables  
   DEALLOCATE AllDatabaseTables  

   CLOSE AllDatabaseNames  
   DEALLOCATE AllDatabaseNames      
END

--EXEC [dbo].[usp_getAllDBTableSizes]
```

In case you need to know, the **rsp_DatabaseTableSizes** table was created through:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[rsp_DatabaseSizes](
    [DatabaseName] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [dbSize] [decimal](15, 2) NULL,
    [DateUpdated] [smalldatetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Riffing on @Mark answer above, added the @updateusage='true' to force the latest size stats (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx):

```
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        DECLARE @TableInfo TABLE (tablename varchar(255), rowcounts int, reserved varchar(255), DATA varchar(255), index_size varchar(255), unused varchar(255))
        DECLARE @cmd1 varchar(500)
        SET @cmd1 = 'exec sp_spaceused @objname =''?'', @updateusage =''true'' '

        INSERT INTO @TableInfo (tablename,rowcounts,reserved,DATA,index_size,unused)
        EXEC sp_msforeachtable @command1=@cmd1 
SELECT * FROM @TableInfo ORDER BY Convert(int,Replace(DATA,' KB','')) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

As a simple extension to [marc_s's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7892349/1501497) (the one that has been accepted), this is adjusted to return column count and allow for filtering:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(

SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.COLUMN_NAME) as ColumnCount,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
INNER JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON t.NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
) AS Result

WHERE
    RowCounts > 1000
    AND ColumnCount > 10
ORDER BY 
    UsedSpaceKB DESC
```

Comment: After you've joined the Columns table, you no longer have the right table space. Outer apply will be the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample query to get tables larger than 1GB ordered by size descending.

```
USE YourDB
GO

DECLARE @Mult float = 8
SET @Mult = @Mult / POWER(2, 20) -- Use POWER(2, 10) for MBs

; WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
    i.object_id,
    Rows = MAX(p.rows),
    TotalSpaceGB = ROUND(SUM(a.total_pages) * @Mult, 0),
    UsedSpaceGB = ROUND(SUM(a.used_pages) * @Mult, 0)
FROM 
    sys.indexes i
JOIN
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
JOIN
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE
    i.object_id > 255
GROUP BY
    i.object_id
HAVING
    SUM(a.total_pages) * @Mult > 1
)
SELECT 
    SchemaName = s.name,
    TableName = t.name,
    c.TotalSpaceGB,
    c.UsedSpaceGB,
    UnusedSpaceGB = c.TotalSpaceGB - c.UsedSpaceGB,
    [RowCount] = c.Rows
FROM 
    CTE c
JOIN    
    sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
JOIN
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
ORDER BY
    c.TotalSpaceGB DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this query to be easy to use & quick.

```
select schema_name(tab.schema_id) + '.' + tab.name as [table], 
cast(sum(spc.used_pages * 8)/1024.00 as numeric(36, 2)) as used_mb,
cast(sum(spc.total_pages * 8)/1024.00 as numeric(36, 2)) as allocated_mb
from sys.tables (nolock) tab
inner join sys.indexes (nolock) ind 
    on tab.object_id = ind.object_id
inner join sys.partitions  (nolock) part 
    on ind.object_id = part.object_id and ind.index_id = part.index_id
inner join sys.allocation_units (nolock) spc
    on part.partition_id = spc.container_id
group by schema_name(tab.schema_id) + '.' + tab.name
order by sum(spc.used_pages) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you only care about the empty wasted space in the database and not the individual tables you can consider the following:

If the database experiences large amount of data insertion and then deletions, maybe like in an ETL situation, this will cause too much unused space in the database as the file groups **auto-grows** but never auto-shrinks back.

You can see if this is the case by using the **Properties** page of your database. You can shrink (right click on the database > Tasks > Shrink) and claim some space back. But, if the underlying reason is still there, the database will grow back (and consume extra time trying to grow back and things gets slowed down until it grows enough - so don't do it in that case)

[image: (KEK: key encryption key)]

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp_table_info
(
id int identity(1,1),
tblname varchar(200)
);
CREATE TABLE #SpaceUsed 
(
     TableName sysname
    ,NumRows BIGINT
    ,ReservedSpace VARCHAR(50)
    ,DataSpace VARCHAR(50)
    ,IndexSize VARCHAR(50)
    ,UnusedSpace VARCHAR(50)
) 

insert into #tmp_table_info
select s.name+'.'+t.name 
from sys.tables t 
inner join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where t.type = 'U';

declare @min int =1,@max int = 0
select @max = count(*)
from #tmp_table_info
while(@min<=@max)
begin
    declare @tablename varchar(200)
    select @tablename=tblname
    from #tmp_table_info
    where id =@min

    DECLARE @str VARCHAR(500)
    SET @str =  'sp_spaceused '''+@tablename+''''
    INSERT INTO #SpaceUsed 
    EXEC (@str)  
    set @min =@min + 1
end;
select @@SERVERNAME as servername,DB_NAME() as DatabaseName,CONVERT(numeric(18,0),REPLACE(ReservedSpace,' KB','')) / 1024 as ReservedSpace_MB,
CONVERT(numeric(18,0),REPLACE(DataSpace,' KB','')) / 1024 as DataSpace_MB,
CONVERT(numeric(18,0),REPLACE(IndexSize,' KB','')) / 1024 as IndexSpace_MB,
CONVERT(numeric(18,0),REPLACE(UnusedSpace,' KB','')) / 1024 as UnusedSpace_MB from #SpaceUsed
drop table #tmp_table_info
drop table #SpaceUsed
```