# Calculate no of rows created on daily basis from a huge table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to calculate the num of rows created on a daily basis for a huge Table in mysql. I'm currently using

```
select count(1) from table_name group by Date
```

THe query is taking more 2000sec and counting. I was wondering if there's any optimized query or a way to optimize my query.

Comment: Make sure you have an index on the `Date` column.

Comment: Have you looked over here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479677/sql-server-count-is-slow

Comment: Do you really need to recalculate no of rows for past days every single time???

Comment: @peterm I just need the statistics for one time for now to see how many rows are added everyday to my table.

Comment: @Barmar by index on date column means I should add a between clause to limit to a range of date?

Comment: @RishabhAgarwal an index is a modification to the table creation logic.  See: `ALTER TABLE` syntax.  ie: `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX (Date);`

Comment: Oh thanks.... If I create an Index now on Date will it populate itself for all previous entries?

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure that "date" field is of "date" type, not datetime nor timestamp
- Index that column
- If you need it for one day, add a "where" statement. i.e. WHERE date="2013-07-10"

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in items that were created on those dates, you could calculate the count at end-of-day and store it another table.

That lets you run the COUNT query on a much smaller data set (`Use WHERE DATE(NOW()) = Date` and drop the `GROUP BY`)

Then then query the new table when you need the data.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on the `Date` column, there's no other way to optimize this query that I can think of.

```
CREATE INDEX ix_date
ON table_name (Date);
```

Comment: by Index on date column u mean I should add some range of date using between or (<,>) logic clause ?

Comment: No, it means you should create an index in the database. See the updated answer.