# SQL Server: get a report on DB used and unused space

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A customer asked me to create a query to create reports on database space usage, with details for every table.

Thinking it could be useful for others, I post here my solution.

Please post comments and possible improvements. I would like to know, for example, how to get the same results for MySql databases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get size of all tables in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database)

Comment: Thanks, @marc_s. I didn't find that question looking for this solution. My way to answer is quite different from the previous one (maybe mine is worse), but feel free to erase my question if it's useless.

Answer (score 1):

This query works on Microsoft Sql Server 2000+.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 

DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(0) 

-- DB size.
EXEC sp_spaceused

-- Table row counts and sizes.
CREATE TABLE #t 
( 
    [name] NVARCHAR(128),
    [rows] CHAR(11),
    reserved VARCHAR(18), 
    data VARCHAR(18), 
    index_size VARCHAR(18),
    unused VARCHAR(18)
) 

INSERT #t EXEC sp_msForEachTable 'EXEC sp_spaceused ''?''' 

SELECT *
FROM   #t

-- # of rows.
SELECT SUM(CAST([rows] AS int)) AS [rows]
FROM   #t

DROP TABLE #t
```