# Can't find TfsVersionControl Administration Job

Tags: sql-server, database, tfs, jobs, sql-server-2016

im using tfs 2017 update 3; i want reduce my tfs database size;
so i want clean up it;
i cant find TfsVersionControl Administration Job in job list and when i run this code : 
        use [msdb];
        go

```
    select
       CAST (name as varchar(60)) as job_name,
       job_id,
       enabled
    from 
       sysjobs
    order by
          name;
    go
```

i cant see any job;
i searched about it and i find a little information about this;
can i deploy this job manually ??? how????

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. This is a product specific issue.

Comment: @jarlh sql server 2016 enterprise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS VersionControl Administration Job is obsolete since TFS2010, so you could not find it, because TFS 2017 does not use it.

[**Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/architecture/background-job-agent) windows service is installed with TFS server on the application tier and executes maintenance jobs on all TFS databases.

If you want to reduce your tfs database size, there are a couple of ways to clean your TFS database:

- [tf destroy command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control)
- [Test Attachment Cleanup Tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2011/03/18/managing-tfs-2010-how-to-clean-up-test-attachment-data/)
- [witamin (destroying work items)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/witadmin/remove-work-items-permanently)

You could also reference this [blog](https://mattyrowan.com/2014/04/02/need-help-tfs-tbl_content-table-and-database-growth-out-of-control/) to reduce the TFS database size. Another way is shrinking the **transaction log** in TFS. How to do it please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45006677/5391065).