# Estimate the Size of all Tables in your SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to know which tables in my SQL server database are fairly large in size. I found a SQL function that calculates an estimate size of a table ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175991.aspx)), but it does not support to list it for all of the available tables. Is there a way to do so? I've managed to write the function within a TSQL script, it does answer my question, however it isn't the most beautiful way to solve it.

```
DECLARE @table_name varchar(100)
DECLARE @tables TABLE (table_name VARCHAR(255), column_list VARCHAR(255));

SELECT * INTO #tmp_tables FROM (
SELECT o.name AS table_name,
    STUFF(
    (
        SELECT ', ' + c.name
        FROM sys.columns AS c
        WHERE c.object_id = o.object_id
        ORDER BY c.column_id
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '') AS column_list
FROM sys.objects AS o
WHERE type = 'U') table_names

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmp_tables) > 0
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1 @table_name = table_name FROM #tmp_tables;
print @table_name;
EXEC Sp_spaceused @table_name;
DELETE #tmp_tables where table_name = @table_name;

END
DROP TABLE #tmp_tables;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that [Sp_spaceused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx) should be applied on all of the tables in the DB if the parameter is omitted.

If this is not true,
I would use `MSforeachtable` to [iterate through all of tables](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/324992/Getting-List-Of-Tables-Of-An-Specific-Database-Usi) and call `Sp_spaceused` on each of them, and then sum the result.

```
sp_msforeachtable ' Sp_spaceused ''?'' '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this is a single query. Query [`dm_db_index_physical_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917.aspx) to get the size of all partitions in the database. Join that to the other usual meta-data tables such as `sys.indexes` and `sys.objects`.

Comment: I see it linked to this question, which is fairly the elegant version of what I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database?lq=1