# How to size table by number of rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table where I want to get size of the number records based on byte
In SQL Server:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to know the size of given table in bytes or you want to count the number of records.

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database

Comment: Please rewrite the question as this is not clear enough to understand.

Comment: **I ask the question a different way Want to condition number record gain 
Then their weight gain **<br>--How Size table By Condications 
==>select * from dbo.PictureTable where SchoolCode=1001<==

Comment: IMO, A result of a query is a `View` not a `Table` and a View has no space over your storage !?

Comment: ** I know, but I want to know the number of records Weight table Not All Records Table **

Answer (score 0):

The only answer related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database) that I can suggest is this:

```
SELECT
    s.name AS SchemaName,
    t.name AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    a.total_pages * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB,
    a.used_pages * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB,
    a.total_pages * 8 / p.rows AS eachRowTotalSpaceKB,
    a.used_pages * 8 / p.rows AS eachRowUsedSpaceKB,
    a.total_pages * 8 / p.rows * (select * from dbo.PictureTable where SchoolCode=1001) AS queryTotalSpaceKB,
    a.used_pages * 8 / p.rows * (select * from dbo.PictureTable where SchoolCode=1001) AS queryTotalSpaceKB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    s.name = 'dbo' AND
    t.name = 'PictureTable';
```

---

**Edit**
You can get length of your data in a field by using [DATALENGTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) like this:

```
SELECT SUM(DATALEGTH(PictureTable_ID)) + SUM(DATALEGTH(Groupcourses_ID)) +SUM(DATALEGTH(per_ID)) + SUM(DATALEGTH(School_ID)) + SUM(DATALEGTH(AcademicYear_ID)) + SUM(DATALEGTH(PictureTable_Description)) + SUM(DATALEGTH(SchoolCode)) As rowSizes
FROM PictureTable
WHERE (SchoolCode = 1001);
```

Comment: Is All Weight table  -- I Went Custom Number Records Weight In Table

Comment: If you want to know the data length of each row I add an edited info to my answer ;).

Comment: Thanks Is real Solutions