# Query to find Size for each table By Filtering Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, size

The Following Code will display the Size of each table in database

```
USE DatabaseName
GO

CREATE TABLE #temp (
      table_name SYSNAME
    , row_count INT
    , reserved_size VARCHAR(50)
    , data_size VARCHAR(50)
    , index_size VARCHAR(50)
    , unused_size VARCHAR(50)
)
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT #temp
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'sp_spaceused ''?'''
SELECT a.table_name
     , a.row_count
     , COUNT(*) AS col_count
     , a.data_size
FROM #temp a
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns b ON a.table_name COLLATE database_default
    = b.table_name COLLATE database_default
GROUP BY a.table_name
       , a.row_count
       , a.data_size
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(a.data_size, ' KB', '') AS INTEGER) DESC
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Is there any way to Find the Space of All table by filtering the Row.
Like I have Foreign Key `Company ID` In All Table would it be possible if i want to know the space Occupied by Company

---Example ---

```
Purchase Table :

P_ID   P_Description   P_Price    P_CompanyID
------------------------------------------
1         Mobile        100          1 
2         Laptop        2100         1
3         Table          50          2

Sale table:

S_ID   s_Description   S_Price    S_CompanyID
------------------------------------------
1         Mobile        110          1 
2         Laptop        2200         1
3         Table          100         2

OutPut table:

Table         Size      Company  
--------------------------------- 
Purchase      1.5MB        1 
Sale          1.5MB        1         
Purchase      1MB          2           
Sale          1MB          2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get size of all tables in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database)

Comment: Hi Piyush  
Thanks for Reply.the link you share that one I know ... that one is for table Size. I want to table size with restricted rows 
thanks

Comment: Have a small question... What's wrong in my previous answer? :) BTW delete old questions is a bad idea

Comment: Not by querying the metadata, no. You could query the *actual* data and do a calculation on it, but it's not going to be nearly as cheap as the metadata query.

Comment: @Devart  Sorry For Deleting my Old Question. I am new to stackoverflow. You asked me for output. I tried to put in comment.but I am unable to put in comment so i had put in question. no body reply so i thought you havn't notice my question. that is reason i put new so every one see my requirement. Sorry for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have Found the solution as per my Requirement. Thanks to Devart Help.

```
DECLARE @tblNAME NVARCHAR(50) = ''
DECLARE @colNAME NVARCHAR(50) = ''
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR
SELECT NAME
FROM   SYS.TABLES
WHERE  TYPE = 'U'
     AND SCHEMA_ID = 1
     AND name NOT LIKE 'tt_%'

OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @tblNAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

   SELECT @colNAME= c.name
        FROM sys.columns c,sys.objects o
        WHERE c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
            AND c.name like '%_CompanyID' And o.name=@tblNAME
        if @colNAME is null or @colNAME =''
            begin 
             FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @tblNAME
            end
        Else
        Begin    

             -- PRINT @tblNAME
              --Print '---'+ @colNAME



              SELECT @SQL += '

IF OBJECT_ID(''tt_' + o.name + ''') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [tt_' + o.name + ']

SELECT *
INTO [tt_' + o.name + ']
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id])) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + '
WHERE '+@colNAME+' =10' -- your condition
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
    AND o.name NOT LIKE 'tt_%'
    AND o.name LIKE @tblNAME
    AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM sys.columns c
        WHERE c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
            AND c.name like '%_CompanyID' -- your column
        )



          Set @colNAME=null
              FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @tblNAME

             end
  END

CLOSE CUR

DEALLOCATE CUR 


Print @SQL


 EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT REPLACE(o.name, 'tt_', '') as TableName, t.Size, t.Total_Rows, '1' as IsClient
FROM sys.objects o
JOIN (
    SELECT
          i.[object_id]
        , size = SUM(a.total_pages) * 8. / 1024
        , total_rows = SUM(CASE WHEN i.index_id IN (0, 1) AND a.[type] = 1      THEN p.[rows] END)
    FROM sys.indexes i
    JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.[object_id] = p.[object_id] AND i.index_id =     p.index_id
    JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.[partition_id] = a.container_id
    GROUP BY i.[object_id]
) t ON o.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
WHERE o.name LIKE 'tt_%'
    AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND o.[type] = 'U'
    ORDER BY t.size DESC

SET @SQL = ''
SELECT @SQL += '
DROP TABLE [' + o.name + ']'
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
AND o.name LIKE 'tt_%'
AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```