# TFS Database growing rapidely

Tags: database, tfs, sql-server-2012

My TFS Database is growing rapidely. I need to know how I can figure out what is taking most of that space and find a way to destroy the information that I don't need to keep.
We are using GIT inside TFS. Does GIT in TFS manage Branches the same way it does on our PC or it create a copy of all the files?

At the end, I would like to reduce the required space for the database file.

thanks

Comment: You need to specify what version of TFS.  But I'm guessing that someone (or several people) are checking in binary files into source control and using it as a file repository.  Instead of a source control repo.  TFS compares the text of files and stores the deltas.  If it can read the files as text (.dll, .exe) then it just stores the check ins as new files.  It's close to impossible to reduce the size of TFS dbs

Comment: tfs 2015. no binary files (bin folder and obj)

Comment: Run this query against the collection database https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database  Let us know which table or top 5 tables are using the space

Comment: Rules is the top one. Then, tbl_GitCommitChange come second and Constants third.

Answer (score 1):

Files aren’t stored on the file system like they would be when git is running on your local machine. Instead they are stored in the TFS SQL server database.

If there are many users who frequently modify and commit the changes, the tables you mentioned will be growing accordingly.

You can refer to [this article](https://www.richard-banks.org/2014/02/tfs-internals-how-does-tfs-store-git.html) to see how the git files are stored, then figure out what caused the Database growth.

Normally, the files you committed/attached will be stored in tbl_Content Table, so, you can also check if there is the abnormal growth for that table based on [this article](https://mattyrowan.com/2014/04/02/need-help-tfs-tbl_content-table-and-database-growth-out-of-control/).

To clean up and reduce the size of the TFS database, there are a couple of ways to clean your TFS database:

- [tf destroy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control)
- [Test Attachment Cleanup Tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2011/03/18/managing-tfs-2010-how-to-clean-up-test-attachment-data/)
- [witamin (destroying work items)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/witadmin/remove-work-items-permanently)

You can also reference this article:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19932.reduce-the-size-of-tfs-databases-after-cleaning-some-source-control-files.aspx