# How to calculate openfire conference room chat messages data

Tags: database, openfire, conference

I have developed the Chat application using Openfire XMPP server, I would like to know the data consumption for storing the messages in the database for conference chat room.

Comment: "The data" <- which data? You need to be way, way more specific.

Comment: I mean the data consumption for storing the message in the database.

Comment: that's not really clear, still, but you should probably edit your question to include that info. Generally, asking as clearly and with as much background as feasible is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inquire `OFMUCCONVERSATIONLOG` table.

To check disk usage, you must follow procedure related to your database (that is a generic question, already discussed somewhere).

I can link answer like this:

[Get size of all tables in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database)

or

https://serverfault.com/questions/132620/oracle-how-to-find-out-storage-space-used-by-a-table