# How do I see which table has taken up how much storage space?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

How do I see which table has taken up how much storage space in Microsoft SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get size of all tables in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check space used by a particular table then you can use the below query

**Single Table**

```
EXEC sp_spaceused N'yourtableName'
 GO
```

**For all the tables**

```
sp_msforeachtable 'EXEC sp_spaceused [?]' 
GO
```

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way -> In SSMS's Object Explorer, right-click on the database, select Reports -> Standard Reports -> Disk Usage by Table.

Another simple way -> In SSMS, launch Object Explorer Details, drill down to a table, and select it. In the results pane, you'll see the size of that table.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Greg. I wish I could mark more than one answer as the right one. I was going to mark yours as the right one when I discovered I couldn't see the Reports context-menu item when browsing a SQL Azure database in SSMS. But Mukesh Arora's query did work on SQL Azure as well. Nevertheless, your suggested query works well on local databases and I found your answer to be very helpful. :-)