# Need Db audit info query in SQL Server for these columns

Tags: sql-server

Will you please provide a single query in SQL Server to fetch audit information of databases and tables in the server as below?

Database audit should include record count for each table, table size, database size and drive size in the server including Server name.

Comment: sorry, but we can't. it's secret knownledge preserved only for community members and readers of [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81245/how-to-determine-the-size-of-my-tables-in-the-sql-server-database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

For single table pass the table name as shown below.

```
exec  sp_spaceused N'dbo.MyTable'
```

For all tables use the below query.

```
exec sp_MSForEachTable 'exec sp_spaceused [?]'
```