# How can I determine the data size of each table?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm working on a SQL Server database and want to see how much space each table has without looking at each one individually. Is there a tool in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 or a SQL query and find out the data size?

I have already searched the web but unfortunately only found advertisements.

I would be very grateful for any advice.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at my response here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database/7892349#7892349 - this is a SQL query you can run to get the table sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a report with Table size in **SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)**
Select you database, then
**Reports>Standard Reports>Disk Usage By Table**

[image]

Comment: Okay thx for ur quick answer. It works but its a little bit laggy because i have more than 60000 tables. Do i have the opportunity to save this list?

Comment: found it! Thanks for ur help :)

Comment: Yes you can save the report, by exporting it to the format you wish (excel, word, PDF)