# How can we find a table size from .duckdb file

Tags: python, duckdb

I have a .duckdb file inside which, I have been creating duck db files. However, I now just want to understand the size (MB/GB) of a table from the .duckdb file. Is there a way for this?

I have tried show all tables, Describe but they do not seem to be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can try this which [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database) wrote:

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS TableName,
    s.name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.object_id > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.name, s.name, p.rows
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC, t.name
```

or write click On Database then 'Reports' then find 'disk usage by Tables'.